# Links of menus not work [Wordpress]

Tags: wordpress

I have problems with menu links. My Wordpress is hosted at http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/mytheme. My links have a format of http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/mytheme/my-menu-link.php. I want them to have a format of http://localhost/wp/my-menu-link as the default Wordpress themes. I do not know how to configure so that my links are generated in this way. The theme is own.

I am using the base tag in my head with the format http://localhost/files/wp/wp-content/themes/mytheme/, if this does not work for me css, js etc.

Anyway the functions of Wordpress do not work with this format of links.

**The code of my menu.**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="header" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </button>
                          <a id="logo" href="/"></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="/" class="first"><span class="fa fa-home"></span>Inicio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="noticias.php"><span class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></span>Noticias</a></li>
                            <li><a href="eventos.php"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>Eventos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="acerca.php"><span class="fa fa-info"></span>Acerca</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contacto.php"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span>Contacto</a></li>
                          </ul>

                          <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                             <li class="dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span>Asociarme</a></li>
                            </li>
                          </ul> -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

I will be careful.

Regards

Comment: Have a look this link:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918687/wordpress-custom-links-in-menu-not-working?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918687/wordpress-custom-links-in-menu-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: Registering the menu is the only way to solve my problem? Adding the functions.php file and registering there the menu would already work ?. I must also register the pages that link the menus ?, for example I have a page news.php that contains the news, I must also register that page ?. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create pages in your dashboard, which you want to show as links, after creating pages, make a Menu (Go to Appearance-> Menus in your dashboard) for them and add all the pages in the menu. Now you have to call wp_nav_menu() function with your menu location in it. Replace this function with complete " ul " tag.
Hope it will solve your problem.